# Specific Word Request For a Word Similar To Narcissist

Tags: single-word-requests

***Sample sentence***: "I'm no narcissist, young lady. I am a _____" (something like that. A title or name of a state of mind.)

Despite my search for this word through book thesauruses and google's version i have not found a word that fits the criteria i have in place.

***Description of the desired word***: Much like a narcissist does, this person feels superior to everyone else and tends to look down on people. But, unlike a narcissist, this person has no desire of special treatment, power over people, or even recognition. And, this person does not think that they are superior due to a lack of flaws. They think they are better only relatively, much like a RC car without batteries is better than an RC car without wheels.

(If you do not have a word that matches or a method for me to find it, don't stress. I am, more or less, sure this word does not exist. At least in English.)

Comment: elitist? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitism

Comment: Could be if the person had a status reason or proven superiority much like a true elite.

Comment: *I'm simply superior* perhaps?

Comment: If you know the word in another language, please tell us.

Comment: Unfortunatly i only speak english. I just make the statement that I don't believe english has a word for this is because where english lacks, other languages have words for specific ideas. I know an example but I forgot the specific word. It's Russian and it means "one who gains pleasure from others pain". But I think it's different from sadist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds very close to a [***misanthrope***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misanthrope):

> A person who dislikes humankind and avoids human society. (Oxford Dictionaries)

Now, the definition doesn't *require* a sense of superiority—a misanthrope might be just as self-loathing as other-loathing—but in practical application the misanthrope often seems to exclude him- or herself from the general hate-fest, at least to some degree. Compare, for example, the famous misanthropic quote by Samuel Johnson:

> “I hate mankind, for I think myself one of the best of them, and I know how bad I am.” (Quoted in [*The Life of Samuel Johnson, LL. D.* By James Boswell, 1826](https://books.google.com/books?id=LIjvV9VYRT0C&dq=%E2%80%9CI%20hate%20mankind%2C%20for%20I%20think%20myself%20one%20of%20the%20best%20of%20them%2C%20and%20I%20know%20how%20bad%20I%20am.%E2%80%9D&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CI%20hate%20mankind,%20for%20I%20think%20myself%20one%20of%20the%20best%20of%20them,%20and%20I%20know%20how%20bad%20I%20am.%E2%80%9D&f=false))

Unlike your typical *egotist* or *narcissist*, however, a *misanthrope* with a superiority-complex is unlikely to seek out “special treatment, power over people, or even recognition” because that would require contact with people. In fact, Molière's Alceste, the original Misanthrope, decides that because he is (or maybe so that he can be) superior to the lying liars all around him, he must shun all human contact:

> Grayed on all sides, crushed by injustice, I leave a pit where vices triumph, to seek somewhere on earth a lonely spot where I am free to be a man of honor. ([*The Misanthrope*, Act V, Scene VIII](https://archive.org/stream/misanthropecomed00molirich/misanthropecomed00molirich_djvu.txt))

So you could say

> I'm no narcissist, young lady. I am a **misanthrope**.

Comment: Very well done. That seems to fit very well actually thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Snob** Definition 3b https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snob: *one who has an offensive air of superiority in matters of knowledge or taste*

This may answer your specification
*this person feels superior to everyone else and tends to look down on people....this person has no desire of special treatment, power over people, or even recognition*

Comment: The short italic description you first give isn't the definition of snob I know. I've rechecked it in the dictionaries?  Perhaps you can provide a reference.  My understanding of the distinguishing feature of a snob is their desire to only associate with those of high social standing OR who acts offensively to those they consider inferior.

Comment: Editing to reflect the key point: this person feels superior to everyone else and tends to look down on people.

Comment: Yes, that feels more accurate to the word. You're right that basically the word snob is about not wanting to associate with those below them, ignoring them more than expecting any sort of treatment from them. It could work for what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Well that would be a narcissist pretty much. The difference is that this person treats nobody like they are beneath them. Just feels like they are. I don't know if i'm just being nit picky about definitions or not so i may be wrong in trying to be so specific.

Comment: Something I have found interesting about some high-functioning autistic type (think Asperger) people I know is that often those who do not know them well think exactly this way of them (that they think themselves superior, but don't seek to control).

Answer (score 1):

**I'm no narcissist, lady. I'm a realist.**

Sorry. Couldn't help myself.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for reading though

Comment: Humorous, but this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This term isn't exactly correct, however, it is one of the few terms that **cast a positive light** on one that believes they are better.

> [**noblesse oblige** at Google search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=noblesse%20oblige&oq=noblisse&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (differs from usual Oxford reference)
>   phrase of noblesse
>
> 1.
>   the inferred responsibility of privileged people to act with generosity and nobility toward those less privileged.
>
> *"there was to being a celebrity a certain element of noblesse oblige"*

Also,  while it might sound counter-intuitive, a true **"noble"** might also be a noble person of the best sense.

> [Definition of ***noble*** -- Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noble)
>
> 1a :  possessing outstanding qualities :  illustrious was a noble king
>
> 1b :  famous, notable noble deeds
>
> 2 :  of high birth or exalted rank :  aristocratic
>
> *… my sire is of a noble line … — Samuel Taylor Coleridge*
>   noble families
>
> 5
>   :  possessing, characterized by, or arising from superiority of mind or character or of ideals or morals :  lofty a noble ambition a noble cause

Answer (score 1):

Although you are looking for a noun, I think the adjective "proud" works.    As a noun meaning the proud person, it seems to have died out by the 17th century.  OED's first sense of the word is "Having a high or exalted opinion of one's own worth."  It adds "Usually in a negative sense: disposed to feeling superior; having inordinate self-esteem; haughty, arrogant."  But I think you'll find most words with this meaning have negative connotations.

Comment: +1 I think proud is a good possible answer, although your answer itself could use some improvement.  The site requires links to definitions from outside sources and a bit of formatting would help your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**No brag, just fact.**

...from the Guns of Will Sonnett back in the day.  [Youtube clip (10 sec)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9j1qkorFszY)

You'd have to restructure the sample sentence a bit:

"I'm better, but I'm no narcissist, young lady.  No brag, just fact."

Comment: I actually like that phrase. might use it personally

Answer (score -3):

> [Megalomania](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/megalomania) - a mania  for great or grandiose performance

A person with megalomania is **megalomaniac** which is quite a close match

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: It would help, in posting your opinion as an answer, to show a source for comparison.  NVZ mentions long answers, but it's more like *thorough* answers beyond one sentence.  In this case, the request is for a milder word than Narcissist, not more power hungry, so show the reasoning *behind* thinking you found a close match.

Comment: Megalomaniac: "a person who is obsessed with their own power" (Oxford Living Dictionary). Nope, this doesn't match with "this person has no desire of [...] power over people"